# How to get training data for Keras Sequential CNN into the correct tensor shape?

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a 4 dimensional tensor of image pixel data (Red(height, width), Green (height, width), Blue (height, width), 14000 examples) and a CSV file containing the coordinates of the bounding boxes that each image has ie, (Image name, X1, Y1, X2, Y2), it has 14000 rows, one for each example, as well.

How do I feed this data to my neural network? Currently, if I try feeding the tensor it passes the entire array of 14000 examples against one row of (X1,Y1,X2,Y2) {it should have passed one array for one row of x1,y1,x2,y2}.

Any idea how to fix this?

Here's the code and the associated error:

```
train_csv = pd.read_csv('datasets/training.csv').values
test_csv = pd.read_csv('datasets/test.csv').values

y_train = train_csv[:,[1,2,3,4]]   #done
x_train_names = train_csv[:,0]     #obtained names of images in array

#### load images into an array ####
X_train = []
path = "datasets/images/images/"
imagelist = listdir(path)
for i in range(len(x_train_names)):
img_name = x_train_names[i]
img = Image.open(path + str(img_name))
arr = array(img)
X_train.append(arr) 


#### building a very basic classifier, just to get some result ####
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Convolution2D(64,(3,3),input_shape=(64,64,3), activation = 
'relu')) 
classifier.add(Dropout(0.2))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D((4,4)))
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32,(2,2), activation = 'relu')) 
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(16, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))
classifier.add(Dense(4))
classifier.compile('adam','binary_crossentropy',['accuracy'])
classifier.fit(x=X_train,y=y_train, steps_per_epoch=80, batch_size=32, 
epochs=25)
```

Error:

ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 14000 arrays:

```
[array([[[141, 154, 144],
         [141, 154, 144],
         [141, 154, 144],
         ...,
         [149, 159, 150],
         [150, 160, 151],
         [150, 160, 151]],

        [[140, 153, 143],
         […
```

**EDIT**: I converted all my images to grayscale so I don't get a memory error. This means that my X_train should have 1 dimension along the number of channels (earlier, RGB). Here's my edited code:

```
y_train = train_csv[:,[1,2,3,4]]   #done
x_train_names = train_csv[:,0]     #obtained names of images in array

# load images into an array
path = "datasets/images/images/"
imagelist = listdir(path)

img_name = x_train_names[0]

X_train = np.ndarray((14000,img.height,img.width,1))

for i in range(len(x_train_names)):
img_name = x_train_names[i]
img = Image.open(path + str(img_name)).convert('L') 
##converting image to grayscale because I get memory error else 
X_train[i,:,:,:] = np.asarray(img)
```

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (480,640) into shape (480,640,1)

(At `X_train[i,:,:,:] = np.asarray(img)` line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is always to find out which input shape your first convolution layer expects. The documentation of [tf.nn.conv2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d) states that the expected shape of the 4D input tensor is `[batch, in_height, in_width, in_channels]`.

To load the data we can use a numpy ndarray. For that we should know the number of images you want to load, as well as the dimensions of the images:

```
path = "datasets/images/images/"
imagelist = listdir(path)

img_name = x_train_names[0]
img = Image.open(path + str(img_name))

X_train = np.ndarray((len(imagelist),img.height,img.width,3))

for i in range(len(x_train_names)):
 img_name = x_train_names[i]
 img = Image.open(path + str(img_name))
 X_train[i,:,:,:] = np.asarray(img)
```

The shape property of your X_train tensor should give you then:

```
print(X_train.shape)
> (len(x_train_names), img.height, img.width, 3)
```

EDIT:

To load the images in multiple batches you could do something like this:

```
#### Build and compile your classifier up here here ####

num_batches = 5
len_batch = np.floor(len(x_train_names)/num_batches).astype(int) 

X_train = np.ndarray((len_batch,img.height,img.width,3))

for batch_idx in range(num_batches):
    idx_start = batch_idx*len_batch
    idx_end = (batch_idx+1)*len_batch-1
    x_train_names_batch = x_train_names[idx_start:idx_end]

    for i in range(len(x_train_names_batch)):
        img_name = x_train_names_batch[i]
        img = Image.open(path + str(img_name))
        X_train[i,:,:,:] = np.asarray(img)

    classifier.fit(x=X_train,y=y_train, steps_per_epoch=num_batches, batch_size=len(x_train_names_batch), epochs=2)
```

Comment: There are around 50,000 images in the dataset, using this code gives me a MemoryError at `X_train = np.ndarray((len(imagelist),img.height,img.width,3))`.
I have 16gb of RAM and 64 bit Python so I'm not sure why I'm getting this.. any idea?

Comment: Do you run out of memory during training set generation or during the training? I estimate the total file size of the 50000 64x64x3 images to be around 5 gb, right? However, during the forward pass the required memory is substantially increased. Try decreasing the batch size or the number of feature maps. If that isn't sufficient, you should load only a part of the images into the training set at a given time. Keras also provides a more sophisticated [dataloader](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) which is exactly made for that case.

Comment: One more thing: Cast the X_train tensor explicitely as uint8 type like so: `X_train = np.ndarray((len(imagelist),img.height,img.width,3), dtype=np.uint8)`

Comment: I'm thinking of converting the images in the grayscale format for this, Florian. I get that error when executing that code itself, I don't get to even reach the training/test part. I think there's a memory issue when creating the array itself. Anyway, I edited my code a bit to use the grayscale, can you help me? Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Hi Sakazuki. For your greyscale approach you have to reshape your image like this: `X_train[i,:,:,:] = np.asarray(img).reshape((img.height, img.width, 1))`. If that works, thats fine for a start. However you might loose classifcation performance when operating on grayscale, since you are "throwing away" the color information. Instead, you could just load the color images in multiple smaller batches. I will update my main answer to give you an example for that.

Comment: This worked! I didn't know I would have to reshape the array, thank you for guiding me :D

Comment: Glad I could help :) Updated my answer with the alternative approach. You could give that a try, too. But most importantly just keep playing around :)